# Using Add-on packages in Blender scripts

Tags: add-on

I was wondering how I could import (if possible) modules from installed add-on packages.

The enabled add-on I am currently using includes these classes, which I want to import into my script:
https://github.com/rdb/blender-egg-importer/blob/master/importer.py

`importer.py` is part of this add-on package called `blender-egg-importer`, which is already loaded in.

[image: imported]

How can I call these classes from this add-on package using a script in the text editor?

Comment: Have you tried `from blender_egg_importer import importer` ?